# Spring Batch integration Java DSL and RunIdIncrementer not incrementing

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration

I have a spring boot/integration/batch which will run and poll files on SFTP.

I'd like to be able to eventually relaunch a job (could be because application has been restarted or because for some reasons we received the same file again) with the same parameters (same file basically) using `RunIdIncrementer` defined on Job's Configuration.

Unfortunately run.id=1 doesn't increment and I get a `JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException`

**JOB configuration**

```
@Autowired
private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilders;

@Bean
public Job importOffersJob() {

    Job job = jobBuilders.get("importOffersJob")
            .start(importOffersStep)
            .listener(traceJobExecutionListener())  
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .build();

    return job;
}
```

**Integration**

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow ftpInboundFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Sftp.inboundAdapter(SftpSessionFactory())
                .regexFilter(".*\\.xml.mini$")
                .deleteRemoteFiles(intCfg.getSftpDeleteRemoteFiles())
                .preserveTimestamp(Boolean.TRUE)
                .autoCreateLocalDirectory(Boolean.TRUE)
                .remoteDirectory(intCfg.getSftpRemoteDirectory())
                .localDirectory(new File(intCfg.getSftpLocalDirectory())
            ), 
                e -> e.id("sftpInboundAdapter")
                .poller(Pollers.fixedRate(intCfg.getSftpPollerInMinutes(), TimeUnit.MINUTES).maxMessagesPerPoll(1)))
            .transform(fileToJobLaunchRequestTransformer())         
            .handle(jobLaunchingGw())
            .handle(logger())
            .get();
}
```

---

```
public class FileToJobLaunchRequestTransformer implements GenericTransformer<Message<File>, JobLaunchRequest> {

    private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileToJobLaunchRequestTransformer.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("importOffersJob")
    private Job job;

    @Override
    public JobLaunchRequest transform(Message<File> source) {
        log.info("FileToJobLaunchRequestTransformer, source.getPayload().getAbsolutePath(): {}", source.getPayload()
                .getAbsolutePath());

        JobParametersBuilder jobParametersBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();
        jobParametersBuilder.addString("pathToFile", "file:" + source.getPayload().getAbsolutePath());
        //jobParametersBuilder.addString("UUID", UUID.randomUUID().toString());

        JobParameters jobParams = job.getJobParametersIncrementer().getNext(jobParametersBuilder.toJobParameters());

        return new JobLaunchRequest(job, jobParams);
        }
     }
```

If I uncomment  `jobParametersBuilder.addString("UUID", UUID.randomUUID().toString());` It's is working but I think the point is to be able to reuse the incrementer defined in my job configuration isn't it ?

(When I was running the same batch as a simple spring boot without integration the incrementer was working)

many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RunIdIncrementer.getNext()`:

```
public JobParameters getNext(JobParameters parameters) {

    JobParameters params = (parameters == null) ? new JobParameters() : parameters;

    long id = params.getLong(key, 0L) + 1;
    return new JobParametersBuilder(params).addLong(key, id).toJobParameters();
}
```

You are creating a new job parameters each time so it will always return 1 because `run.id` doesn't exist.

If you move the `jobParametersBuilder` to a field in the transformer, alongside `job`, it will work, but only for this instantiation of your app. It will start again at 1 the next time you start your app.

To survive restarts, you need to save off the `run.id` value somewhere, or you need to get the last job parameters from the repository.

Comment: Thanks Gary, your answer is useful, but I still don't get why my @autowired Job doesn't use the incrementer defined in its configuration  `.incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())`. Is it the expected behaviour ? Also any ideas why it was incrementing when I was launching as a simple spring boot application (seems that it was getting the last job parameters from the repository automatically)? Lastly if i need to get the last job parameters from the repository should I reuse `JobInstanceDao` or there is already some helpers to achieve that? thanks!

Comment: I'd have to see your working configuration, especially how you build the job parameters. `> doesn't use the incrementer `. It __is using the incrementer from the job__, it's just that you are passing in a vanilla `JobParameters` each time within `transform()`. Since this new JP has no `run.id`, it always gets set to 1.

Comment: This was the working configuration! I did few tests and my conclusion is that I was not reading the persisted state to retrieve the last good parameters for the job. I've borrowed the code from [link]https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/support[link]/CommandLineJobRunner.java `getNextJobParameters` and put it in my transformer `FileToJobLaunchRequestTransformer `, and now I can see my run.id incrementing. I thought the incrementing part was part of the magic of job's configuration. Thanks again Gary!