# Spring Batch and Quartz scheduling, row change by multiple transactions

Tags: spring-batch, quartz-scheduler, spring-batch-admin

I have a Spring Batch (3.0.6) / Spring Batch Admin (2.0 snapshot) application that I'm attempting to schedule jobs with using Quartz (2.2.2).  Using batch admin config for hsqldb (we don't care about this data at all) we're getting a multiple transaction change error when running the Quartz jobs (though the Spring Batch jobs are kicked off and completing fine).

I receive the following error:

```
    [2016-05-02 16:28:16.005] boot - 48230  INFO [scheduler_Worker-2] --- MyJobBean: Launching myBatchJob
[2016-05-02 16:28:16.014] boot - 48230  WARN [scheduler_Worker-1] --- MyBatchJob: Job failed with Exception PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; transaction rollback: serialization failure; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: transaction rollback: serialization failure
java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: transaction rollback: serialization failure
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:873)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:866)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:629)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:866)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:927)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:932)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobInstanceDao.createJobInstance(JdbcJobInstanceDao.java:115)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:135)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean$1.invoke(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy61.createJobExecution(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:125)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:130)
    at com.app.MyBatchJob.performJob(MyBatchJob.groovy:41)
    at com.app.MyBatchJob$performJob.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:114)
    at com.app.MyJobBean.executeInternal(MyJobBean.groovy:36)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:75)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: transaction rollback: serialization failure
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: transaction rollback: row change by multiple transactions
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.TransactionManagerMVCC.addInsertAction(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.addInsertAction(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Table.insertSingleRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.insertSingleRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementInsert.getResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDMQL.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation; JOB_INST_UN table: BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Constraint.getException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.index.IndexAVLMemory.insert(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.RowStoreAVL.indexRow(Unknown Source)
    ... 49 more
```

I've boiled it down to this simple config (read a list of items, convert to upper case and print them) and I still get this error. 
The job configuration in `groovy`...

```
@Bean
public ItemProcessor<Object, Object> processor() {
    return new ItemProcessor<Object, Object>() {
        @Override
        Object process(Object item) throws Exception {
            return item.toString().toUpperCase()
        }
    }
}

@Bean
public ItemReader<Object> reader() {
    return new ListItemReader<Object>(['John', 'Jill', 'James', 'Jenny'])
}

@Bean
public ItemWriter<Object> writers() {
    return new ItemWriter<Object>() {
        @Override
        void write(List<?> items) throws Exception {
            items.each {
                println("List item : $it")
            }
        }
    }
}

@Bean
public Job myJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("myJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .flow(myStep1())
            .end()
            .build()
}

@Bean
public Step myStep1() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("myStep1")
            .<Object, Object> chunk(10)
            .reader(reader())
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writers())
            .build()
}
```

Here's the quartz bean config (cron schedule for every 15 minutes):

```
@Bean
public SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler() {
    SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean = new SchedulerFactoryBean()
    schedulerFactoryBean.setTriggers(myTrigger().getObject())
    schedulerFactoryBean.start()
    return schedulerFactoryBean
}

@Bean
public CronTriggerFactoryBean myTrigger() {

    CronTriggerFactoryBean cronTriggerFactoryBean = new CronTriggerFactoryBean()
    cronTriggerFactoryBean.setCronExpression("0 0/15 * * * ?")
    cronTriggerFactoryBean.setJobDetail(myJobFactory().getObject())
    return cronTriggerFactoryBean
}

@Bean
public JobDetailFactoryBean myJobFactory() {
    JobDetailFactoryBean factory = new JobDetailFactoryBean(jobClass: MyJobBean,
            name: MyJobBean.JOB_NAME)
    return factory
}
```

The QuartzJobBean :

```
@Log4j
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
class MyJobBean extends QuartzJobBean {

    public static final JOB_NAME = "myBatchJob"

    @Override
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        log.info("Launching $JOB_NAME")

        ApplicationContext applicationContext = ApplicationContextUtil.getAppContext()
        MyBatchJob myBatchJob = applicationContext.getBean(JOB_NAME, MyBatchJob.class)

        try {
            myBatchJob.performJob()
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("Quartz job failed with cause $e.message", e)
        }
    }
}
```

The class that launches a batch job via the `JobLauncher` and `JobLocator` of spring batch:

```
@Log4j
@Component
class MyBatchJob {

    @Autowired
    private JobLocator jobLocator

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher

    public void performJob() {

        try {
            JobParameter timestampParam = new JobParameter(System.currentTimeMillis())

            def paramMap = [:]
            paramMap.put("timestamp", timestampParam)

            JobExecution jobResult = jobLauncher.run(jobLocator.getJob("myJob"), new JobParameters(paramMap))
            log.info("Job launched with result $jobResult")

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("Job failed with Exception ${e.getMessage()}", e.getCause())
        }


    }

}
```

Relevant properties for spring batch admin:

```
batch.job.configuration.package=com.app.jobs
batch.business.schema.script=classpath:business-schema-hsqldb.sql

ENVIRONMENT=hsqldb
```

The quartz job fails with an Exception but the Spring Batch job runs and completes just fine. I'm at about my wits end as to fixing the Quartz job. Anyone see anything I'm doing wrong with my configuration ?

**UPDATE:**
When I remove Spring Batch Admin, this error goes away.  If I switch from `@EnableBatchAdmin` back to `@EnableBatchProcessing` the exception does not get thrown.  Now, I'm trying to figure out what between the default config of batch vs batch admin is causing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that the line of `new RunIdIncrementer()` creates new Incrementer each time, which results in 1 id each time, hence the exception that you get of unique constraint at BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE table.
You need to store it somewhere and access it each time. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31120264/3883957).

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not it.  This happens on the very first execution with a fresh db, so there is definitely no duplicate. Also, I'm including the current timestamp as a `JobParameter` so that the job key is always unique.

Comment: Also, the `@Bean` method is only run once at time of startup/first execution since there is no `@JobScope` or `@StepScope` annotation which would cause it to run once per job/step. I've also confirmed that run.id is always being incremented as expected.

Comment: The Exception occurs right at the first time, no need to wait for the 2nd run of the quartz job? you can see the new BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE row in the table at the DB? seems valid?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to query and see the records in there. The data is valid.

Comment: And the Exception occurs right at the first time, no need to wait for the 2nd run of the quartz job?

Comment: Yes, definitely occurs during the first run (and every run), no need to wait for 2nd run.

Answer (score 0):

What's the isolation level on your `JobRepository`? You may want to knock it down to `ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED` if it is currently `ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE` (ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE is the default).

```
<bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean" 
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
    p:transactionManager-ref="transactionManager">
    <property name="tablePrefix" value="${batch.schema}.BATCH_" />
    <property name="isolationLevelForCreate" value="ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I was using the default, but now I've tested with `ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED` and even `ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED` and the behavior stays the same.